# **by/on** foot."?

Tags: prepositions

Suppose I am trying to tell someone, how much distance google maps shows if we take car or on foot. How would I say this?

"My house is 10KM from here by car and 8 KM **by/on** foot."

I think "by" is used for means of transport but is it correct to use this here or "on" foot sounds appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both; although technically, **on** is more accurate and common.

In the context of your sentence, *by* may be used for a foot as a tool used for movement, and *on* -- for a foot as the part of a body on which this body moves, which, in my opinion, doesn't make any difference.

For a possibility of using "by foot" you may also see [here](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/say-on-foot-by-foot/).

Answer (score 1):

You can say "by car" and "on foot".

However, the following are usual and more idiomatic:

My house is a 10-kilometer drive from here.

My house is a 8-kilometer walk from here.